# How does one enable Compiz on Alienware M11x R2?

Tags: compiz, nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid

I want to enable compiz on my Alienware m11x r2 but when I try to I get a message that I have to enable Nvidia propietary drivers and I can't enable them because it will cause problems with next startup because the nvidia is the discrete GPU of my laptop, I had done a search this [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1402584&postcount=45) and [here](http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com).

But I seem to not get it working right. I have also tried the vga-swticheroo thing with no results at all.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to change the option in the UI because it doesn't realize you may have more than one GPU. However, you can use `gconf-editor` to change /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager to compiz and then on your next login effects should be enabled. If you can't wait you can just run `compiz --replace &` in a terminal to get effects running for your current session.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you must force Nvidia Graphic card turn on in Bios. On Windows you can switch between both graphic processors but on Ubuntu there is no such option yet. Imho better to force Nvidia to work always and this for sure solve problem. :>

Answer (score 0):

nVIDIA it doesn't work in Alienware M11x R2, (Optimus Technology is not support yet in Linux) but you can enabled with Intel Graphic Card.

Only install compizconfig-settings-manager

Open a terminal:

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Then go to Desktop. Right-click mouse. Select "Change Background". Go to "Visual Effects" and select "Extra". Apply changes.

Then go System-Preferences-OptionsCompizConfig's Administrator. And enable your effects

Enjoy It.

Blackout ...

PD.- Sorry for my English but I'm Mexican

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Ubuntu Control center( Firstly download and install [Font Manager](http://font-manager.googlecode.com/files/font-manager_0.5.5-4_i386.deb) and [Jstest-gtk](http://ucc.googlecode.com/files/jstest-gtk_0.1.0-1~getdeb1_i386.deb) then install [Ubuntu control center](http://ucc.googlecode.com/files/ucc_051_i386.deb)) which has VGA Switching Module and can switch between high and low graphics mode.

[image]